# Cognos BI 10.2.2 Connection with the LDAPS

Tags: cognos

I have a requirement within my company to setup a Cognos Connection with the LDAPS instead of regular LDAP server.

We have Multiple Domain Controllers & I am not sure how to make connection to multiple Domain Controller within Cognos.As when you do a Cognos Configuration you have to specifiy the Host & port Information .

Comment: What's the difference between " the LDAPS" and "a regular LDAP server"? Do you have a particular LDAP database with a custom schema? I can tell you that Cognos has many guides on doing this. I suggest you find a guide, follow it and come back with any specific questions

Comment: Could you clarify the set up more?  With more information people around here could certainly point you in the right direction.  You mention Domain Controllers for example; are you connecting to Active Directory?  Or is this just a term you're assigning to another LDAP server?